# Apache Ivy. Transitive dependencies not retrieved

Tags: java, ant, dependency-management, ivy

I have 3 projects of the following structure:

```
App
|  |
  ...
|  |
|  +--lib
|  |    |
|  |    +--...
|  |
|  +--dist
|
Lib
|  |
   ...
|  |
|  +--lib
|  |    |
|  |    +--sublib-1.0.jar
|  |
|  +--dist
|       |
|       +--lib-1.0.jar
|
SubLib
   |
  ... 
   |
   +--dist
        |
        +--sublib-1.0.jar
```

Which have the following relation:

```
App <-- Lib <-- SubLib
```

I am using apache ivy to retrieve the dependencies for both `App` and `Lib`. The dependencies are described as follows:
`ivy.xml` of `Lib`:

```
<ivy-module version = "2.0">
    <info organisation = "com.test.lib" module = "lib"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org = "com.test.sub.lib" name = "sublib" rev = "1.0" conf = "compile->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

`ivy.xml` of `App`:

```
<ivy-module version = "2.0">
    <info organisation = "com.test.app" module = "App"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org = "com.test.lib" name = "lib" rev = "1.0" conf = "compile->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

`ivysettings.xml`:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver = "local"/>    
    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name = "local">
            <artifact pattern = "${ivy.settings.dir}/SubLib/dist/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
            <artifact pattern = "${ivy.settings.dir}/Lib/dist/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>    
    <modules>
        <module organisation = "com.test.ivytest" resolver = "local"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

**Expected result:** after executing `ivy:retrieve`, both `sublib-1.0.jar` and `lib-1.0.jar` to be present in `App/lib`

**Actual result:** only `lib-1.0.jar` is present in `App/lib`. The generated ivy-report for `App` does not contain any mention of `sublib` being a dependency of `lib`. Nothing of a sort is in ant + ivy logs during build as well.

*Note:* `lib-1.0.jar` is not being built as a fat-jar.

What am I missing in this configuration?

---

*Update*

I've done some thinking, and the only conclusion I came with is that this problem is indeed misconfiguration. Judging by the fact, that transitive dependency is not retrieved, we can positively say that ivy does not have any information of a sort when it resolves `lib`. And that makes sense, because `Lib/dist` folder could be anywhere in the file system. The only way to have information about transitive dependency would be having respective `ivy.xml` somewhere close to that jar. Which is not. This is slightly confirmed by the message in logs `[ivy:retrieve] local: no ivy file found for com.test.lib#lib;1.0: using default data`. The only way that information is preserved is cache data in `%user%/.ivy/cache`. There the generated `[org]-[artifact]-[conf].xml` files do contain the dependency information. So I'm guessing for that to work properly, I will have to use cache on App's resolution level.

Does that make any sense or am I plainly wrong again?

Comment: ivy:resolve should be called before retrieve. What ere the errors that you get? IS there something like "configuration missing"?

Comment: From what I was able to understand is that it's not necessary. I see for `[ivy:retrieve]` sections in logs that it does perform a resolve. I get no errors, it's just transitive jar dependencies missing.

Comment: Ok (reading the updated part also) could please do clear ivy cache and run it again. Also add to the question the ant script(s) that you are using to publish `lib` and `sublib`.

Comment: `ivy:cleancache` is explicitly called during `App.clean` ant task. It's just not mentioned. I'm testing one idea at the moment, if it works properly, I'll post it here.

Comment: Can you show the full ant command you use ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the problem was indeed the bad configuration and my lack of understanding it. Here is the detailed explanation how to make it work. I'm not really good with terminology, so I may have misused some words here. Let's look at project configuration and what's what.

`Sublib` is going to be a **runtime** dependency for `Lib` **that has a compile-time** dependency `guava`.

```
SubLib
   |  `lib
   |      `guava-19.0.jar
   |
    `dist
   |    `--sublib-1.0.jar
   |
    `src
        `...
```

So, we need to make appropriate configurations in SubLib's `ivy.xml`:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.test.sub.lib" module="sublib"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.google" name="guava" rev="19.0" conf="runtime->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Here, by declaring a `runtime` configuration we state that this `ivy.xml` describes a module that is a runtime-time dependency. And since guava has no such file we describe it as default. Pretty standard here. Now, for others to know that `sublib-1.0.jar` actually has a dependency from `guava-19.0.jar` we need to publish it to a repository, so that such information exists in form of file `ivy-[version].xml` next to the jar. I chose to publish into the `build` folder. To do so, `ivysettings.xml` needs to contain a resolver that helps to match file patterns for publishing and later on on retrieval when we'll resolve from `Lib`.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="filesystem-resolver"/>

    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="sublib-resolver">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/SubLib/dist/repo/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/SubLib/dist/repo/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>

        <filesystem name="filesystem-resolver">
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/SubLib/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>

    <modules>
        <module name="sublib" organisation="com.test.sub.lib" resolver="sublib-resolver"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

`sublib-resolver` will allow to find the corresponding `ivy-[revision].xml` that has information about the dependencies and the location of `jar`. Whereas `filesystem-resolver` will find our `guava` dependency. Now we just publish `sublib` with `ant` by invoking our resolver:

```
<target name="publish">
        <ivy:publish artifactspattern="${dist.dir}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
                     resolver="sublib-resolver"
                     overwrite="true"
                     pubrevision="${revision}"
        />
</target>
```

Now to `Lib`. Lib is going to be a **compile-time** dependency for `App` and we describe it as such in `ivy.xml` and declare `SubLib` as a **runtime dependency** for it:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.test.lib" module="lib"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public"/>
        <conf name="runtime" extends="compile" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.test.sub.lib" name="sublib" rev="2.0" conf="runtime->compile"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Here's where configuration comes in play and what I didn't understand at first. `runtime->compile` Left hand side is understandable: `sublib` was declared as a runtime dependency and we assigned it to `runtime` conf in it's ivy file. On the arrow's right hand side we state that we want `sublib`'s compile-time dependencies as well. And the one that was configured as such is `guava`. It will be found by the resolver and retrieved as well. So, we need a resolver for `Lib` as well, so complete `ivysettings.xml` file will look like this:

```
<ivysettings>
    <properties file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.properties"/>

    <settings defaultResolver="filesystem-resolver"/>

    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="sublib-resolver">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/SubLib/dist/repo/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/SubLib/dist/repo/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>

        <filesystem name="lib-resolver">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/Lib/dist/repo/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/Lib/dist/repo/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>

        <filesystem name="filesystem-resolver">
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/SubLib/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>

    <modules>
        <module name="sublib" organisation="com.test.sub.lib" resolver="sublib-resolver"/>
        <module name="lib" organisation="com.test.lib" resolver="lib-resolver"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

And publish of `Lib` in `Lib`'s `build.xml`:

```
<target name="publish">
        <ivy:publish artifactspattern="${dist.dir}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
                     resolver="lib-resolver"
                     overwrite="true"
                     pubrevision="${revision}"
        />
</target>
```

Now to the main problem: transitive retrieval. Configurations. In `App`'s `ivy.xml` we need to specify exactly that we want transitive dependencies. The information that they exist stored in repos is not enough. One must specify it in `App`'s `ivy.xml`:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="compile" visibility="public"/>
</configurations>

<dependencies>
    <dependency org="com.test.lib" name="lib" rev="1.0" conf="compile->compile; compile->runtime"/>
</dependencies>
```

What happens here is the following: by declaring `compile` conf we state that `App` has a compile configuration. The first arrow chain, like before, states that we (compile-configured module `App`) want to get compile-configured dependency called `lib`. Left and right arrow sides respectively. And the second arrow set states that we (compile-configured module `App`) want to get **runtime-configured dependencies of `lib`**! Which is `sublib`. And since it comes together with `guava` it is retrieved as well.

---

A little messy explanation, and may very not be the most elegant one for a solutioin, but it's the only way I managed to make this work properly at all. If anyone knows any better ways of doing so, any help would be appreciated.